# Term expansion before compiling in GNU Prolog

Tags: prolog, gnu-prolog

Given the following tuple of directive + predicate:

```
:- web_resource(plaintext/1, [content_type(text/plain)]).
plaintext(Result) :-
    ...code...
```

how do I tell `gplc` to transform this code into

```
plaintext([headers(['Content-Type'-'text/plain']),
           payload(Payload)]) :-
    old_plaintext(Payload).

old_plaintext(Payload) :-
    ...code...
```

before compiling it? `old_payload` can be defined recursively.

Comment: I think you can also use assert and retract predicates

Answer (score 1):

GNU Prolog [term-expansion](http://www.gprolog.org/manual/gprolog.html#expand-term%2F2) is currently limited. But you can use Logtalk (which supports GNU Prolog) term-expansion mechanism to achieve that transformation. In a nutshell, define a Logtalk [hook object](https://logtalk.org/manuals/glossary.html#term-hook-object) with your expansion rules and then expand your Prolog source files, by using the `logtalk_compile/2` predicate. Something like:

```
:- object(my_expansion,
    implements(expading)).

    term_expansion((:- web_resource(Name/Arity, Headers) Clauses) :-
        % construct clauses
        ...

:- end_object.
```

and then:

```
$ gplgt
...
| ?- {my_expansion}.
...

| ?- logtalk_compile('my_source_file.pl', [hook(my_expansion), scratch_directory('.']).
...
```

The last query will result in a new Prolog file saved in the current directory with the expansion results. You can them compile this file using `gplc` as usual. For more details on the portable Logtalk term-expansion mechanism see:
https://logtalk.org/manuals/userman/expansion.html